# Does the Facebook Graph API support audio file uploads?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, audio, post

Is it possible to upload an audio file (i.e. mp3, flac...) to the the Facebook Graph? If so could any one point me toward a resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no you cannot post audio files directly to facebook wall.

However you CAN post embedded flash to play your audio.

Here's the resource to posting flash players to wall:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/486/

Comment: Is this feature available in the special music API for white listed users?

Comment: this is still available even if you're not in the whitelist of Facebook's Music API. This is a different approach currently available to all.

Comment: The linked blog post is an empty white-screen on my end.